# Flutter AnimatedOpacity turns grey in release mode?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I've been trying out my app in release mode and have noticed that widgets that use animated opacity show a grey out blank over them then disappear once the animation has finished. I was wondering if anyone knows how to stop this.

```
AnimatedOpacity(
  opacity: aniProg,
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
  child: ...
)
```

I know that they grey represent an error occurring however when I use it in debug no error crops up

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation with AnimatedContainer and AnimatedOpacity, switching to the stable channel solved this issue. I think it is a bug in the master channel.